# Display link as a link in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I am using js/jquery to do a find and replace in a contenteditable div. I want to replace `#hath` with `<a href="#" id="pid:00000" contenteditable="false">Hathaway</a>`

http://jsfiddle.net/atlchris/VSJ6E/

The find and replace all works good, but how can I make the link I am inserting be active (clickable) instead of being a actual tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
$('#field').text(newText);
```

to:

```
$('#field').html(newText);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ichr/u75hN/1/